# WPF Treeview with HierarchicalDataTemplate - items not selectable

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have searched couple of hours to fix this issue. but no luck.

I have **treeview** (two levels). each treeview item contains `checkbox` and `textblock`. I have added command binding to textblock and after adding it treeviewitem not selectable.

how to fix this.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCategories, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>                
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">                        
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"  Command="{Binding DataContext.ProductCategoriesCheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
                </CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Category}" >
                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding DataContext.ProductCategoriesSelectCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" MouseAction="LeftClick" CommandParameter ="{Binding Category}" />
                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ProductCheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
                        </CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Product.Name}">
                            <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                <MouseBinding Command="{Binding DataContext.ProductSelectCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" MouseAction="LeftClick" CommandParameter ="{Binding Product.Name}" />
                            </TextBlock.InputBindings>                                    
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Textbolck without **MouseBinding** will work fine. Is there any other control that I can use instead of textblock with click command binding.

**EDIT**
This is I have implemented the command from my viewmodel

```
    RelayCommand _productSelectCommand;
    public ICommand ProductSelectCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if ( _productSelectCommand == null)
            {
                 _productSelectCommand = new RelayCommand(param => ProductSelect((string)param));
            }
            return _productSelectCommand ;
        }
    }

    public void ProductSelect(string productName)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Have you implemented `ICommand.CanExecute` properly?

Comment: for the command `ProductSelectCommand`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan-have updated may question with the command I have used from code behind

Answer (score 0):

If you use `RelayCommand` from `MVVM Light Tollkit` you can use this:

```
if ( _productSelectCommand == null)
{
     _productSelectCommand = 
                new RelayCommand(
                                   param => ProductSelect((string)param),
                                   p => true
                                );
}
```

or implement your logic related when the command could be run.

Comment: did it. but no luck still :(

Comment: The `Binding DataContext.ProductCategoriesSelectCommand` looks like strange. Check your binding errors in output window. In which class do you have implemented the `ProductCategoriesSelectCommand`? I think you must use `Binding ProductCategoriesSelectCommand` instead.

Comment: sorry. I didn't get your question. you mean with out using `MouseBinding` use `binding`? If so binding is not supported. can you please provide me a sample

Comment: Please note:this command binding work fine. current issue is when I click on treeview item, that item not get selected. other that command is executing fine